# What does "[warn] Query '[scrubbed]' didn't have valid rend desc in cache. Failing." mean?

Tags: onion-services, support, log

I am transferring files over Tor and I am seeing the following message in my Tor log file.
Can someone explain what it means?

```
[warn] Query '[scrubbed]' didn't have valid rend desc in cache. Failing.
```

Comment: There's the code https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob/HEAD:/src/or/rendclient.c

Comment: It seems that the client fails to find a valid descriptor for the rendezvous point in its cache. It's used for the hidden-service you connect to. I think it is better to contact support for this. (https://www.torproject.org/about/contact.html.en#support)

Comment: I removed some lines in error. The code is in Line 1105 to 1110, but to me it is not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term `rend desc` refers to a rendezvous descriptor. This is a special node for hidden services. In your case this information is missing and so it fails.

If I understand it correctly you can wait a few minutes and retry your connection. There is a chance that you'll get a rendezvous descriptor this time..